# Unexpected extra ghost value in dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, ftp, ftplib

I am writing a Python script that downloads files from an ftp location using the `ftplib` module. The files I download are specifically named `whatsnew.txt` and are located inside `{ftp location}/{folder}/{subfolder}` and there are many such folders and I download all `whatsnew.txt` located in them.

The way I do it is that before downloading, I gather what the directory tree of the ftp location looks like and store it as a dictionary (I also save this dictionary, formatted as a json file, in an output file named `directory_tree.txt`).

Now, when I parse this dictionary to get the values for {folder} and {subfolder}, there is an unexpected extra value in the dictionary, specifically the `/318/08` as seen in the image. `318` is the folder and `08` is the subfolder. I have no idea where the hell did this ghost entry came from.

[image: image: error in retrieving from unexpected ftp location]

It is unexpected since this is what the folder in question looks like:

[image: contents of 318 folder in ftp]

There is no frickin' `08` subfolder.

Here is a snippet of my code (Python 2.7.9) where I think I went wrong. How can I resolve my error? How do I fix this extra value? I hope there is no need for exorcism. Hopefully just exorcism of my programming insufficiency. Thanks.

```
for folder in directory_tree["ControlPatch_CPR"]: //Loop for checking dict entries
    for subfolder in folder:
        print str(folder) + " --- " + str(subfolder)
for folder in directory_tree["ControlPatch_CPR"]:
    for subfolder in folder:
        if len(subfolder) == 1:
            subfolder = "0" + subfolder
        ftp.cwd("/")
        print "\nretrieving {0}/ControlPatch/{1}/{2}/whatsnew.txt ...".format(ftplocation, folder, subfolder)
        with open("{0}.{1}.whatsnew.txt".format(folder, subfolder), "wb") as whatsnew:
            ftp.cwd("/ControlPatch/{0}/{1}".format(folder, subfolder))
            print "working directory: " + ftp.pwd()
            ftp.retrbinary("RETR /ControlPatch/{0}/{1}/whatsnew.txt".format(folder, subfolder), whatsnew.write)
```

Also, I am scared.

Comment: This code looks innocuous.  I would instead look at whatever populates the list of subfolders in the `directory_tree` dict member in the first place. The requirement to add a leading zero looks weird as well -- if you are not populating the list of subfolders from the actual FTP server's listing, all the more reason to assume that this code is at fault, rather than the code you are showing us. Maybe the output from the first loop would be helpful as well -- again, the `str()` calls look suspicious. Why aren't these things strings already?

Comment: I posted an answer since it was resolved. By the way, the part that you pointed out which has a `str()` was just for debugging purposes and has no effect on the data. Though I realized using `str()` was redundant :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed(?) my problem, though I can't explain it. From the code I posted above, I changed a part from:

```
for folder in directory_tree["ControlPatch_CPR"]:
    for subfolder in folder:
        if len(subfolder) == 1:
```

to:

```
for folder in directory_tree["ControlPatch_CPR"]:
    for subfolder in directory_tree["ControlPatch_CPR"][folder]:
        if len(subfolder) == 1:
```

This part `directory_tree["ControlPatch_CPR"][folder]` is a list thus I thought doing `subfolder in folder` just refers to `folder` as the same iterable. Anybody care to explain? Thanks.

Anyway, problem's solved. Whew. I can now return to my computer.